# vba how to pick up a shape format

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably very simple but I cannot spot the error in my code below which is supposed to copy the format of the shape named xx and apply it to shape named yy. Thanks for any help.

```
  Sub CopyPasteShapeFormat()
  Set myDocument = Worksheets("Shape Object - Methods")
  With myDocument
        .Shapes("xx").PickUp
        .Shapes("yy").Apply
  End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: It correctly copies the **format** of shape "xx" to shape "yy" for me.  (E.g. I had an orange rectangle called "xx" and a blue triangle called "yy", and it changed the triangle to be orange.)

Comment: you ask for help, but you do not say what is wrong.

Comment: it simply doesn't change the format of the yy shape. There is no error message or something to hint what's wrong. thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change the **format** of the "yy" shape, or are you expecting some other property of the shape to change?  Perhaps include a screenshot of the worksheet showing the two shapes.